# Angular cdk breakpoints and universal issue

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-universal

When rendering angular universal the breakpoint hits come too late. I'm using mat-sidenav which expects the drawer to be set opened or not based on a breakpoint. It seems that the breakpoint information isn't there when rendering ssr.

For example, this goes in the constructor:

```
this.isHandset$ = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
        map(result => result.matches)
    );
```

And in the view:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container" fullscreen>
<mat-sidenav class="sidenav" 
    [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">  <!-- close if handset -->
... etc
```

after the app hydrates (after the full angular project loads) the drawer opens / closes as it should based on the viewport size, but initially not.

How to make breakpoints also work with universal?

I'm currently using angular 9 rc, but same problem in 8.

Comment: You can inject values from your back end. `renderModule` which is used for ssr can accept parameters, these parameters can be set up as injectables and used in your components.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a *default* value that is emitted first before any breakpoints using [startWith](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/startwith.html).

```
this.isHandset$ = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
        map(result => result.matches),
        startWith(false)
    );
```

Comment: although I like your answer (I'm using an behavioursubject now), users on desktop (or mobile) will then still see the opposite layout for a second.

Comment: Hi @ElgerMensonides, How did you solve your problem?

Comment: @user9714967 ended up ditching mat-sidenav en used css media queries. There's no other way since angular needs to be bootstrapped for breakpointobserver to work. My next projects will move back to bootstrap :(

Comment: You can inject values from your back end. `renderModule` which is used for ssr can accept parameters, these parameters can be set up as injectables and used in your components.